# Why does my String formatter makes the argument 0.00 instead of its actual value

Tags: ios, swift, string, xcode, format

Im hoping this is a small fix, but I have a textfield which is a number that the user puts in.  It's outlet is called billTextField.  I need to change it to a float/double instead of a string, but I want it so that it doesn't go past two decimal places.  I debugged, and when I go

```
Double(billTextField.text ?? "") ?? 1
```

it prints the correct value, but when I try to use a string formatter

```
Double(String(format: "%.2f", billTextField.text ?? "")) ?? 2
```

the value becomes 0.00, even if my text field says 125.50 or any other number.  I assume it must be the string formatter causing this, any ideas?

Comment: The %.2f argument expects a floating point value, not text. When you say you don't want the input to go past two decimal places, do you mean you want to prevent the user from inputting more than two decimal places, or just that you want your double representation to discard anything past two decimal places? These two goals have different solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the issue is with `String(format:)` you need to provide the second parameter as `Double`, here's how:

```
let doubleValue = Double(billTextField.text!) ?? 0 // You can force unwrap strings since it never returns nil credits @Leo
let roundedDoubleValue = Double(String(format: "%.2f", doubleValue)) ?? 2
```

Or use `round`on Double like this:

```
let roundedDoubleValue = Double(round(100*doubleValue)/100) // number of zeros for number of places
```

Comment: Text property will never return nil. It’s default value is an empty string

Answer (score 0):

i think it is because you try to covert string into string hence that is why you got 0.00.

but you can get away by this

```
  let dubleNumber = Double(billTextField.text!) ?? 0
  let formatter = NumberFormatter()
  formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
  formatter.string(for: dubleNumber)
```

Comment: Text property will never return nil. It’s default value is an empty string